# Find a path that contains all relationships for a node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to model some database relationships in a graph.  Here is a sample graph from my prototype:

[image]

Blue nodes represent objects.  The green nodes represent relations, or a join, between objects.

If you need to get to object 4, you would need to join with values from both object 1 and 3.

I am trying to query a path from object 1-3:

```
match(one:Object {Name: "1"}),
   (three:Object {Name: "2"}),
    p = (one)-[RELATES*]-(three)
RETURN p
```

This gets me two paths, one that is `(1)-[a]-(2)-[b]-(3)` and one that is `(1)-[c]-(3)`.  The latter is invalid, as all "relates" edges from the graph are not in the path.  Is there a way to filter p accordingly?

Alternatively, is there a better way to model the relationships?

I could represent the edges from a->1, b->2, c->3, & c-1 as a `FROM` and a->2, b->3, and c->4 as a `TO.`

Comment: "The latter is invalid, as all `relates` edges from the graph are not in the path." - do you mean that a path should include all `relates` edges starting from its green nodes? For example, `(1)-[c]-(3)` is invalid as it does not contain `4`?

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant.  There are cases where 2 or more objects are required to lookup another object.  This is an example of one, where the "c" relationship node is for getting to object 4, which requires a path that already has 1 and 3.  Hopefully this makes sense.  I tried originally to model this with edges between object nodes only (no green nodes), but I don't see how it can accommodate such a case.

Answer (score 0):

If it makes sense for you to model the relationships *as relationships*, then you can have this simple graph (where the relationships have type `REL`):

[image]

With this data model, you can get valid paths this way:

```
MATCH p=(:Object {name: '1'})-[:REL*]->(:Object {name: '3'})
RETURN p;
```

Comment: I originally tried a model like this.  The challenge I run into is you need objects 1 and 3 to get to 4.  I was trying to put the relationship node in to facilitate these types of relationships.